# How to calculate the possible number of chess positions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, chessboard

How can you calculate the possible number of legal chess positions (excluding the unachievable combinations). I am interested in how rather than the actual number, meaning , what to consider and what to not. An example with a particular game of chess might be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you searched on MSE and elsewhere? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number

Comment: @e2-e4 "not interested in the actual number , but the "how" part of it.